# Rails where In doesn't recognise where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, where-in

I keep getting an error `undefined method where` when running the code below with these parameters.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

```
 Parameters: {"category_ids"=>["1", "3", "4"]}

    @pieces = Piece.all
    @pieces = @pieces.where(:category_id => params[:category_ids]) if params[:category_ids].present?
    @pieces = @pieces.where(:brand_id => params[:brand_ids]) if params[:brand_ids].present?
    @pieces = @pieces.where(:color_id => params[:color_ids]) if params[:color_ids].present?
    @pieces = @pieces.where(:user_id => params[:friend_ids]) if params[:friend_ids].present?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

`Piece.where(:category_id => params[:category_ids]) if params[:category_ids].present?`

Comment: Even if its a filter that filters through all of them? Perhaps I should use :conditions? -thanks by the way :)

Comment: Or do you mean just the first @piece.where should be Piece.where?

Comment: Piece.all doesn't return you an ActiveRelation. That means, you cannot run a `where` on it. Instead, all Piece.all does is return you an Array of Piece objects.

Answer (score 1):

`User.all` returns you an `Array` of the `user objects` so while using `where` on it gives an error NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for Array

So use following instead

```
@pieces = Piece.where(:category_id => params[:category_ids])
```